# ExtJS Screen reader cannot read X button on mouse over

Tags: javascript, extjs, screen-readers

I need help with screen reader issue. 
To make it screen readable I extended ExtJS window and added `aria-label` attribute.

```
Ext.define('Ext.ux.window.ResultWindow', {
    extend: 'Ext.window.Window',
    alias: 'widget.resultwindow',
    closable: false,
    constrain: true,
    keyMap: {
      scope: 'this',
      ESC: function () {
          this.close();
      }
    },
    tools: [{
      type: 'close',
      ariaAttributes: 
      {
        'aria-label': 'Closing window'
      },
      tooltip: 'Closing window',
      callback: function() {
          this.up('window').close();
      }
    }]
});
```

And if I focus it using TAB key or SHIFT + TAB then it reads it clearly... But if I put mouse over the icon it is not working.

Did someone have an experience with similar problem?